# What is the Bogoliubov transformation matrix for Fermions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-optics

Is there any Bogoliubov transformation matrix for the operator $O=|g\rangle\langle e|$ where $|e\rangle$ and $|g\rangle$ are arbitrary states? I know that, for annihilation and creation operator $a$ for Bosons, the squeezed vacuum generator $S = \exp(\eta^* a^2 - \eta a^{\dagger 2})$ gives
$$S^\dagger a S = \cosh(r) a - e^{-i \theta} \sinh(r) a^{\dagger} \, .$$
Now in my current research, I need to use the transformation
$$S^\dagger | e \rangle \langle g | S =
c_1 | e \rangle \langle g| +
c_2|g \rangle \langle e|
\, ,$$
but I couldn't find the form of $S$, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What is $|a\rangle$? Is it a Fock state?

Comment: @steg It's just an arbitrary state, I will change the notation here.